Form question with optional and mandatory text fields
This question on my registration form is currently shown as options in a dropdown. We are now having to include optional and required text fields based off the selected answer. Will a dropdown still work for this? How can I show those fields?

Do you have all the requested materials?

Yes (if selected show an optional text field)
No because reason a
No because reason b
Other (if selected show required text field)



Yes, hiding and displaying an extra input box conditionally should not be a problem. The other way is to keep the extra input visible but disabled if not required depending on how the users prefer it.

It is a little strange that you also have a text input on the "Yes" case and a "ill-defined" (incomplete) set of "No" answers, but I'll deal with it.
Essentially: Yes, you can use a dropdown to present different answer options. It is sensible to do so, especially if you need to add more options later but do not want to re-arrange the whole screen layout all the time.
The comment field can be presented below the drop-down if needed (I would advocate allowing comments/details in any case, not just for "Yes" and "Other").
Logically speaking you are dealing with a text input which has pre-defined answers for the "No" cases and a  "Other" option which just captures cases not covered in the pre-defined "No"-answers.
So it "should" look like this:
Have Everything?
( ) Yes  
      
( ) No 
+------------------------------+-+
| [Drop down pre-defined list] |v|
+------------------------------+-+

Comment/Details
+--------------------------------+
| [Free text here]               |
+--------------------------------+

But in most cases I know of, the "Yes" case is just part of the drop-down list and the radio button choice is omitted entirely.
In case the user hits "OK" and having selected "Other" in the drop-down and also leaving the text field empty, a friendly reminder should be displayed to give additional information in the text field. Quick solution would be a popup-message (requires confirmation click, that is annoying), better would be to show an inlined text for example below the drop-down field or name the option like "Other - Please give details".
Just keep in mind that the normal "good" path for "Other" is like: [Select "no"], select "other", input text, then hit OK, then check if mandatory input is present. Do not show the reminder directly after selecting "Other" because the user has in mind to give details in this case anyway and a reminder that shi hasn't yet input anything (because the text field is initially empty) would just be obnoxious.
So, essentially my advice is: Don't necessarily distinguish between a mandatory and optional comment field in this scenario. Just allow comments in any case (except you would throw them away anyway - then do not present the comment field of course).
